# Add and retrieve an image from SQL Server using webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to add an image to my SQL Server database and to retrieve it in asp.net web site using a web service.

I don't know what type I need for my column (I saw some examples saying it should be `VARBINARY(MAX)`).

So what I need to do in my web method to show the image in a GridView on the web site, once it is in the database?

P.S. I am using dataset in my service to fill an adapter and return it to the web site.

Comment: how u send a image data to web-service? using encoded string ?

Comment: I dont quite understand what you are asking, but I take the image with sql string = "select * from Pictures", and it retrieve the name and the picture in binary.

Comment: Start with how would you make a GridView dislay a static image, `something.jpg`? Get that to work first, then figure out how to make the image it displays come from your code (maybe have your code return `something.jpg`), then figure out how to get the image from the database. Step by step.

Comment: You should also specify which web service technology you plan to use. You _should_ use WCF or REST, but it would be good to know to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let us imagine hat we have a table with Columns id(int) and image(VARBINARY(MAX)).
To upload the image do this:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("File path and name");
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection string");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [tablename]([id], [image]) VALUES(@id,@image)", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", bytes);

con.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

And there you are the image is uploaded to your database.

To retrieve data from database create one dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, byte[]> images = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
public Dictionary<int, byte[]> GetImages()
{
    Dictionary<int, byte[]> data = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your connection string");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [tablename]", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();
    while(sdr.Read())
    {
        data.Add((int)sdr["id"], (byte[])sdr["image"]);
    }
    con.Close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Ok, once it is uploaded in the database, how to make a web method in the service that will return the image and a gridview in the site show it?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with the datatype, I would indeed choose the VARBINARY(MAX).

An often used method to retrieve images from a database, is by writing an image handler. The images can be request from the handler by url. So if your handler url is /images.ashx?id=1 it could fetch the image from row id 1. Obviously you don't have to use an id querystring parameter, but this is the most straightforward example I can thing of.

Then in your dataset you just return the url's to the image handlers.

This is a good tutorial that does something like this, but uses an aspx page instead of a handler: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-images-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net-GridView-control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply create a new MemoryStream using the received byteArray from the Database and use this MemoryStream to load a bitmap:

```
Dim mem As New IO.MemoryStream(thebyteArray)
Dim img As System.Drawing.Bitmap = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(mem)
```